# What dialect/topolect is 凉薯 a part of?

Tags: topolect

《现代汉语大词典》defines 凉薯 as:

> 方言。即豆薯。有的地方也叫地瓜。藤本植物, 花色浅蓝或白色, 结荚, 种子有毒, 块根像甘薯, 可食。

It was the 方言 part that threw me off here.

[Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%87%89%E8%96%AF/6491956?fr=aladdin) just calls it a

> 别称

other resources also just say something like:

> 又名

I figured 凉薯 was just MSM but apparently it isn't.

What dialect/topolect is 凉薯 a part of? (if not Modern Standard Mandarin.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B6%BC%E8%96%AF#Chinese):

[image]

- 柳州話 (Liuzhou Mandarin)
- 萍鄉話 (Pingxiang Gan)
- 南寧話 (Nanning Pinghua)
- 長沙話 (Changsha Xiang)
- 婁底話 (Loudi Xiang)

These topolects correspond to the areas highlighted in the light green circles above.

Comment: Some local names for it - 紅薯(red skin), 白薯(off white/light tan skin), 甘薯(sweat potato), 番薯(?).

Answer (score 1):

According to Wiktionary, 涼薯 is how you say "jicama" in Beijing and Liuzhou Mandarin, Pingxiang Gan, Shangyou Hakka, Nanning Pinghua, and the Loudi and Changsha varieties of Xiang Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, 凉薯 is part of Modern Standard Mandarin.
As far as I know people in 陕西(Shaanxi)、贵州(Guizhou) call it 地瓜.